# How to set Lock screen message programmatically

Tags: android

In Setting we can set lock screen manually but I want to set lock screen message through programming

[image]

I have tried below approaches:

1. 1.have tried DevicePolicyManager.getDeviceOwnerLockScreenInfo, but it reterning null.
2. I tried to get it using ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, in this there is no field regarding this. I extracted the values of existing fields in this URI but there is no value as we have set for lock screen message.
3. I tried to use LOCK_PATTERN_ENABLED & NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED, these are also not useful.

I have tried all above approached but not able to set and get message if some one has knowledge let me update.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research i got the proper solution by using reflection we can achieve it. There is a **LockPatternUtils** class by which we can get device information, Below is the code.

```
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS}, 1);

    //String a = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(),"lock_screen_owner_info");
    //printLog("a : "+a);

    Class<?> cl = null;
    try {
        cl = Class.forName("com.android.internal.widget.LockPatternUtils");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Constructor<?> cons = cl.getConstructor(Context.class);
        Object obj = cons.newInstance(this);
        Class[] paramInt = new Class[1];
        paramInt[0] = Integer.TYPE;
        Method method = cl.getDeclaredMethod("getOwnerInfo", paramInt);
        Log.d("b : " ,""+ method.invoke(obj, 0));
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```